# PHP won't process on new install

Tags: php, apache, centos

On Centos 7 I have installed HTTPD and PHP5.4 (I know it's old, but a package I am using needs PHP 5.4)

```
[root@devserver sites-enabled]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

[root@devserver sites-enabled]# httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
Server built:   Jun 27 2018 13:48:59

[root@devserver sites-enabled]# php -v
PHP 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Apr 12 2018 19:02:01)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies
```

Apache runs fine and shows that php5 is loaded:

```
[root@devserver sites-enabled]# httpd -M | grep php
php5_module (shared)
```

I have httpd.conf set up to load the module via the 10-php.conf

```
# PHP is an HTML-embedded scripting language which attempts to make it
# easy for developers to write dynamically generated webpages.
#
<IfModule prefork.c>
LoadModule php5_module modules/libphp5.so
</IfModule>

[root@devserver modules]# ls /etc/httpd/modules/ |grep php
libphp5.so
```

However, when I try to load a basic phpinfo page, I only see

```
<?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

Instead of http processing the php. /var/www/html/error.log and /etc/httpd/logs/error.log are both clean. Actually, they're totally empty.

Anybody have any ideas what could be going on?

Comment: As well as loading the module, your web server configuration needs to specify that .php files should be handled with PHP. You could check that that's done

Comment: "a package I am using needs PHP 5.4" I bet it doesn't...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: @Don'tPanic, what further configuration is needed to accomplish that?

Comment: @miken32, unfortunately, it does need that version of PHP. It is a testrail install of a specific version that requires php 5.4

Comment: From the dupe, see this answer specifically: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38952614/1255289